# base controller and apply it to all existing controller

Tags: codeigniter

I need to create codeigniter base controller to check allowed ip address in database by mobel function if the ip is exists then user should go to home page but if the ip address is not exists and show 404 page in codeigniter, i can't find core folder in application folder

Answer (score 7):

First, you need to extend a core class, call it **MY_Controller.php**

Save that file in: **application/core/MY_Controller.php**

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->model('ip_table_model');
        $this->load->library('input');

        // assuming there's a function called "check_ip($ip_address)" in ip_table_model
        if (!$this->ip_table_model->check_ip($this->input->ip_address()) {
             redirect('error_404');
        }
    }    
}
```

Now, we're assuming you have a model called **ip_table_model** which connects to database with list of IP addresses, and there's a function called **check_ip** which will validate whether user has access or not. This is relatively simple, and I won't show any examples on this.

The `redirect('error_404');` page does not yet exist, you need to create a controller which shows your 404 page.

Now, for any other controllers in your project, instead of extends **CI_Controller**, make them extend **MY_Controller** instead.

Here's an example:

```
class Welcome extends MY_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('welcome_message');
    }
}
```

**Explanation:** We're extending **CI_Controller** to create our own core controller, called **MY_Controller**. Inside, we're checking if user has access or not through the constructor, which will be called in every other controller in the project.

**References:**

- http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/core_classes.html
- http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html

Comment: For people who get class not found, check your class name prefix in config file `$config["subclass_prefix"]` and name your core class appropriately

Comment: Is creating a custom core controller considered a good practice (if such a thing really exists)? I am facing a sort of similar situation where i have a custom MVC framework, but want to add custom functions to the core controller so that they will be accessible by all controllers, but i don't want to update the actual core controller. Is creating a custom "core" controller considered a good practice?

Answer (score 2):

Answer is [here](http://www.bohemiawebsite.com/user_guide/general/core_classes.html) (section **Extending Core Class**).

1.7.2 has a different structure to 2.0.*, therefore there is no *core* folder in application

Answer (score 2):

In Core Create a new Class .
Name MY_Controller.php

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {
 // Write your functions here which you wanna use throughout the website
public function abc (){
  echo "Helllo";

}
}


class Welcome extends MY_Controller {

        function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
        }

        function your_custom_fuctions()
        {

            $this->abc(); //echo Hello...
 //Anything you want to do
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function admin_view($view_name = "", $header_info = NULL, $sidebar_info=NULL,$page_info = NULL, $footer_info = NULL, $data_info = ""){

    $this->load->view('Admin/includes/header', $header_info);
    $this->load->view('Admin/includes/Left_sidebar', $sidebar_info);
    $this->load->view($view_name, $page_info);
    $this->load->view('common/footer', $footer_info);
}
```