# Which is the best way to post and process data in codeigniter 3.1.5

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Am little confused to follow the efficient way to post and process data in controller or model in CodeIgniter 3.1.5 (latest)

method:1 In the model

```
public function insert_entry()
{
    $this->title = $_POST['title'];
    $this->content = $_POST['content'];
    $this->date = time();

    $this->db->insert('entries', $this);
}
```

method:2 In Controller

```
public function insert_entry()
{
   $title = $this->input->post("title");
   $content  = $this->input->post("content");
   $date  = $this->input->post("date");

   $data = array(
        'title' => $title,
        'content' => $content,
        'date' => $date
   );
   $this->model->insert($data);
}
```

Then process data and query in the model.

which is the efficient method to follow if we are creating a large scale web application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, there is no best way. Only there is **Good Practice**. Either way, you can archive this. But Model and Controller have different jobs.

Model Only interconnected with the database. And the controller is the one own Load it, initialize, pass it and all.

I personally recommend you is if it's a database related thing use model. Other than any perform it in Controller(Like File Upload, Validations, redirect, load URL).  If we wrote code in an *ethical manner it should understand by another developer*. So if it's messy he/she can't understand any of these. So simply make *it nice and clear* .. always.

---

Read these

1. [Model–view–controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply,I normally code queries in model only.My confusion is with posting data in controller or model. Could you please suggest a method from my post, most developers may follow.Thanks

Comment: what you mean by *posting data in controller or model* what data

Comment: Suppose we have a registration form, so after submitting the form we are sending data using post method (posting) to controller or model.

Comment: Receive it through the controller and validate those. (Ex: check empty, Special Char, if email - format... )and if any error, throw it to view. If all done and success send it to model. So model just does the Update/Insert and returns you the response. So again based on response do the rest in the controller as usual.

Comment: Great! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You should never use `$_POST` directly in CodeIgniter like this without good reason. Doing so means the data will not be automatically sanitized by the framework. The second method is therefore the way to go.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply.So we should write all the logic and conditions in controller itself and call model if there is any database hit , am i correct?

Comment: Not exactly. Ideally you should keep as much business logic as possible out of the controllers (a principle sometimes known as fat models, skinny controllers). Fetching the request data does logically belong in the controllers, however.

Comment: Sorry, wrote models instead of controllers.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some suggestion regarding your question.

First. User [Input Class](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html#CI_Input::post) for post and get.

Base controller is also very helpfull for large scale projects. [base-controller-and-apply-it-to-all-existing-controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8756147/base-controller-and-apply-it-to-all-existing-controller)

Codeigniter has a great validation Libraries [Form Validation](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html)

Mainly I will suggest you is that please read out [Codeigniter User Guide](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/). It is great. I have also started From that.

I am adding some helpful links for better understanding.

1. Here is a Helper link of CodeIgniter forum for [best practices](https://forum.codeigniter.com/forum-12.html)
2. CodeIgniter Documentation

Ok after your comment I will suggest this:
Models meant to be doing all database related functionality. It is not must but as say we always follow the best practices so all DB related functions will be placed in the model.

The posted data form view will come first in the controller. (see input suggestion) then send that data to model and do the further process as required.

Comment: Thank you so much for the suggestion, normally i did all the processing form validation , post data and processing all done in my controller only, but some developers doing like posting all data in model and  execute same query based on posted data in same function (eg : insert_data function in model). That's  why i had this confusion.